# What DbContext should I use with EnityFramework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have .Net Core app with EFCore. I've created ApplicationDbContext class which inherited from IdentityDbContext.

I'd like to use AspNetUsers DbSet for authorization and authentication. Then at powershell console I entered "Update-database" and at my PostgreSQL DB I saw a few tables, including AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers and etc but at project I have only empty ApplicationDbContext.

What should I do then? I can scaffold all entities at DB to object models or extend IdentityDbContext and somehow add properties to aspNetUsers. Moreover, if i scaffold entities I'll get another new DbContext that contains all AspNetUsers ad others.

Comment: Entity Framework uses `DbContext`, all `IdentityDbContext` is, is an implementation with `DbContext` inherited to handle built in Microsoft authorization and authentication mechanisms.  So what do you mean which `DbContext` should you use?

Comment: Depending on your requirements and number of tables, you may consider creating multiple DbContext(s).  Having a [God Context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) can cause numerous programming issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can work with standart implementation of `IdentityUser`, then just inherit `dbContext` from non-generic `IdentityDbContext`.
If you want to create dbContext for Identity with custom User class you need to inherit your custom dbContext class from generic abstract class `IdentityDbContext<T>` where T is your custom implementation of User. This implementation should inherits from already provided by .NET `IdentityUser` class.
Also you need to associate you `dbContext` with Identity in Startup.cs by code like:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyCustomUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyCustomSecurityContext>()...
```

Also I don't know why you are trying to work directly with you Identity context. Usually all work with users, roles, claims is done via specific services (for example `UserManager<MyApplicationUser>`) that hide implementation and provide nice and clear API. You can inject them where you need to.